# Mutually Exclusive Regex Patterns

Tags: c#, regex, rightnow-crm

I am trying to build a set of regex patterns that correctly identify a set of     field types, but cannot figure out how to get them all mutually exclusive.  These syntax conventions always seem to have just enough overlap that I make a match that I don't want to.

---

**Variables**: Capture all

$field

$field_with_underscores

**Standard Fields**: Capture table, capture everything after first dot

$table.field

$table.field.subfield

$table.field.subfield_with_underscores

$table.field_with_underscores

$table.field_with_underscores.subfield

$table.field_with_underscores.subfield_with_underscores

**Custom Fields**: Capture table, capture everything after c$

$table.c$field

$table.c$field_with_underscores

**Custom Object System Attributes**: Capture table, capture object, capture everything after $

$table.object$field

$table.object$field_with_underscores

---

So far, I have the following:

**Variables**: working

```
^\$[a-zA-Z_]+$
```

**Standard Fields**: not working, picks up Custom Object System Attributes

```
\$([a-zA-Z_]+)\.([^c\$][a-zA-Z_\.]+)[\,]?
```

**Custom Fields**: working

```
\$([a-zA-Z_]+)\.[c]\$([a-zA-Z_]+)
```

**Custom Object System Attributes**: working

```
\$([a-zA-Z_]+)\.(?!c\$)([a-zA-Z_]+)\$([a-zA-Z_]+)
```

---

Can someone help me out?  I am quickly running out of hair to pull out...  :\

Comment: What do you mean by `Custom Object System Attributes` ?

Comment: did you mean this https://regex101.com/r/bU2zO2/1 ?

Comment: Custom Object System Attributes is a data type in RightNow.  The strings of that type are formatted like I showed above.  Your regex does not match what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\$([a-zA-Z_]+)(?:\.[a-zA-Z_\.]+)+$
```

You can try this for standard fields.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/bC8aZ4/8

or

```
\$([a-zA-Z_]+)(?:(?!.*\$)\.[a-zA-Z_\.]+)+
```

https://www.regex101.com/r/bC8aZ4/9

Comment: This is really close.  It has me down to the correct sets of fields, but it's not capturing everything after the first dot.  I need it to capture because I use the capture groups.

Comment: @JustinY17 try `\$([a-zA-Z_]+)((?:(?!.*\$)\.[a-zA-Z_\.]+)+)` or `^\$([a-zA-Z_]+)((?:\.[a-zA-Z_\.]+)+)$`

Comment: Both of these options include the first dot (which is not desirable).  So close!

Answer (score 0):

My issue was best solved by the following:

```
\$([\w]+)\.((?!.+\$)(\.?[\w]+)+)
```

Comment: `\w` will include `0-9` as well.Do you want it ?